# Silverstripe check if on first iteration in loop

Tags: silverstripe

How can I check if the loop is on its first iteration?

I want to add a class to a list item but only to the first list, not all of them.

```
<% loop $LatestNews(3) %>
    <% if $this->iteratorPos == 0 %>
    <li class="left-arrow highlight">$Title</li>
    <% else %>
        <li>$Title</li>
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I don't want to do this through javascript.

Comment: considering that your last two questions where well covered by the SilverStripe documentation, may I suggest you consult the documentation first. It not only saves others effort, but in such simple questions also saves you time, as you do not have to wait for a response.

Comment: I usually spend at the minimum 2-3 hours doing my research on these before I ask a question.  Problem with silverstripe documentation is that it has very poor descriptions of its topics and everything seems to be thrown around.  Yes, I use search but I've had very poor luck with my last 2 questions.

Comment: I see, and agree. the SilverStripe documentation could be better. I recommend using google search rather than the search on SilverStripe.org. But you are of course welcome to continue to post your questions here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes, there is.

please see the SilverStripe documentation on Templates, section [Position Indicators](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/templates#position-indicators)

```
<% loop $SomeList %>
    <% if $First %>
        this is the first item<br>
    <% else_if $Last %>
        this is the last item<br>
    <% else %>
        this is item number $Pos<br>
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: I think if you want to check for a particular position number you could do <% if $Pos = 3 %>

Comment: that is correct. But I believe `<% if $Pos == 3 %>` is the recommended way (note the duble =). However, using a single = still works as legacy support